# Manage the path to the venv for pipenv

Tags: pipenv

Is it possible to tell `pipenv` where the venv is located? Perhaps there's something you can put in the pipfile, or something for the `.env` file?

I fairly frequently have to recreate my venv because `pipenv` seemingly loses track of where it is.

For example, I started a project using Pycharm to configure the file system and create my pipenv interpreter. It created the venv in `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-project-ZbEWMGNA` and it was able to keep track of where that interpreter was located.

Switching to a terminal window & running `pipenv` commands then resulted in;

> Warning: No virtualenv has been created for this project yet! Consider running `pipenv install` first to automatically generate one for you or see`pipenv install --help` for further instructions.

At which point I ran `pipenv install` from the terminal & pointed pycharm at that venv, so the path would become `~/apps/my-project-ZbEWMGNA` (which sits alongside the project files `~/apps/my-project`)

Now I've got venvs in both paths and `pipenv` still can't find them.

```
mwalker@Mac my-project % pipenv --where
/Users/mwalker/apps/my-project

mwalker@Mac my-project % pipenv --venv 
No virtualenv has been created for this project yet!
Aborted!

mwalker@Mac my-project % ls ~/apps
my-project
my-project-ZbEWMGNA

mwalker@Mac my-project % ls ~/.local/share/virtualenvs 
my-project-ZbEWMGNA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by setting environment variables. You can set a path for virtual environments via the `WORKON_HOME`. Or have the virtual environment created in the project with `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`.

> Pipenv automatically honors the WORKON_HOME environment variable, if you have it set — so you can tell pipenv to store your virtual environments wherever you want

-- https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-virtual-environment-location

or

> PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT
>       If set, creates .venv in your project directory.

-- https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT

In my experience, PyCharm will uses the existing venv created by Pipenv. Otherwise it will create it in the directory that PyCharm is configured to create it.

Comment: Thanks I missed the part of the docs about `WORKON_HOME`. That'll do what I need.